# How can I force make to exit if compiling one dependency fails?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I've posted the relevant bits of my makefile. When I run `make all` on this makefile, there's a compilation error when compiling `debugosd.o`. However, because make found a previously built `debugosd.o`, it just continues on to build `dialup.otz`.

Without deleting all the .o's, how can I force `debugosd.o` to become out-of-date - and so force `make` to stop as soon as it hits the compilation error in `debugosd.o`?

The rule to build .o files is:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(TITLE)
    $(CC) $(COMPILE) $(C_OPTIONS) -c $<
```

And the makefile snippet is:

```
all: shared0.flw shared1.flw shared2.flw shared3.flw

debugosd.o: debugosd.c debugosd.h
xdialler_interface_new.o: xdialler_interface.h
dialup.ooo: xdialler_interface_new.o debugosd.o xDialler.a
    $(TITLE)
    $(MAKE_OOO)

dialup.otz: dialup.ooo  
    $(BIN)opress $< 

shared1.dir: dialup.otz 
    $(TITLE)
    $(BIN)dirbuild $(SHAREDDIR1_OPTIONS)

shared1.flw: shared1.dir 
    $(TITLE)
    $(BIN)flwbuild $(SHAREDFLW_OPTIONS1)
```

Actually, I figured out what the problem was. I was forcing the rebuild of `shared1.flw` using a phony target. I think this was then forcing `make` to continue regardless of errors.

Comment: Strange, I thought make would already do this.

Comment: Yes, me too - make goes on to build shared2.flw and shared3.flw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no specific subcommands listed for `debugosd.o` so I'm assuming it's using the default, somewhere (such as `.c.o`).

Make should exit if any of the subcommands return a non-zero exit code, *unless the command begins with `-`*. Check the actual command that's being used for the `dubugosd.o` target.

Whether there's a previously built file shouldn't matter, `make` should not carry on after an error condition.